# Show div if no results are found

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, checkbox

I have this code. http://jsfiddle.net/n3EmN/171/
How do I show a div when some checkboxes are checked, and there is no result found, and hide that div when results are found? For example, when I check checkbox "red" and checkbox "africa", there is no result found, so now I have to show a div, how do I do that?

HTML

```
<div class="flowers-wrap">

  <h3 style="font-size:14px; font-weight:normal;">Available Flowers</h3>
  <p style="font-size:12px;"><strong>Filter flowers by colour:</strong></p>
  <form>
    <label style="font-size:12px;">
      <input type="checkbox" name="fl-colour" value="red" id="red" /> Red</label>
    <br>
    <label style="font-size:12px;">
      <input type="checkbox" name="fl-colour" value="yellow" id="yellow" /> Yellow</label>
    <br>
    <label style="font-size:12px;">
      <input type="checkbox" name="fl-colour" value="pink" id="pink" /> Pink</label>
    <br>
    <label style="font-size:12px;">
      <input type="checkbox" name="fl-colour" value="purple" id="purple" /> Purple</label>
    <br>
    <label style="font-size:12px;">
      <input type="checkbox" name="fl-colour" value="green" id="green" /> Green</label>
    <br>
    <label style="font-size:12px;">
      <input type="checkbox" name="fl-colour" value="other" id="other" /> Other</label>
  </form>
  <p style="font-size:12px;"><strong>Filter flowers by size:</strong></p>
  <form>
    <label style="font-size:12px;">
      <input type="checkbox" name="fl-size" value="tiny" id="tiny" /> Tiny</label>
    <br>
    <label style="font-size:12px;">
      <input type="checkbox" name="fl-size" value="small" id="small" /> Small</label>
    <br>
    <label style="font-size:12px;">
      <input type="checkbox" name="fl-size" value="medium" id="medium" /> Medium</label>
    <br>
    <label style="font-size:12px;">
      <input type="checkbox" name="fl-size" value="large" id="large" /> Large</label>
    <br>
    <label style="font-size:12px;">
      <input type="checkbox" name="fl-size" value="giant" id="giant" /> Giant</label>
  </form>

</div>

<div class="continents-wrap">

  <h3 style="font-size:14px; font-weight:normal;">Available Continents</h3>

  <div class="continents" style="font-size:12px;">
    <div>Africa
      <input type="checkbox" name="fl-cont" value="africa" id="africa" />
    </div>
    <div>Europe
      <input type="checkbox" name="fl-cont" value="europe" id="europe" />
    </div>
    <div>Asia
      <input type="checkbox" name="fl-cont" value="asia" id="asia" />
    </div>
    <div>North America
      <input type="checkbox" name="fl-cont" value="north-america" id="north-america" />
    </div>
    <div>South America
      <input type="checkbox" name="fl-cont" value="south-america" id="south-america" />
    </div>
    <div>Antarctica
      <input type="checkbox" name="fl-cont" value="antarctica" id="antarctica" />
    </div>
    <div>Australasia
      <input type="checkbox" name="fl-cont" value="australasia" id="australasia" />
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

<div class="flowers">
  <div class="flower" data-id="aloe" data-category="green small medium africa">Aloe</div>
  <div class="flower" data-id="lavendar" data-category="purple green medium africa europe">Lavender</div>
  <div class="flower" data-id="stinging-nettle" data-category="green large africa europe asia">Stinging Nettle</div>
  <div class="flower" data-id="gorse" data-category="green yellow large europe">Gorse</div>
  <div class="flower" data-id="hemp" data-category="green large asia">Hemp</div>
  <div class="flower" data-id="titan-arum" data-category="purple other giant asia">Titan Arum</div>
  <div class="flower" data-id="golden-wattle" data-category="green yellow large australasia">Golden Wattle</div>
  <div class="flower" data-id="purple-prairie-clover" data-category="purple green other medium north-america">Purple Prairie Clover</div>
  <div class="flower" data-id="camellia" data-category="pink other large north-america">Camellia</div>
  <div class="flower" data-id="scarlet-carnation" data-category="red medium north-america">Scarlet Carnation</div>
  <div class="flower" data-id="indian-paintbrush" data-category="red medium north-america">Indian Paintbrush</div>
  <div class="flower" data-id="moss-verbena" data-category="purple other small south-america">Moss Verbena</div>
  <div class="flower" data-id="climbing-dayflower" data-category="blue tiny south-america">Climbing Dayflower</div>
  <div class="flower" data-id="antarctic-pearlwort" data-category="green yellow large antarctica">Antarctic Pearlwort</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
body {
  font-family: 'Arial';
  color: #646464;
}

.continents-wrap {
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  margin: 0 5% 0 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.flowers-wrap {
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  margin: 0 5% 0 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}

.flowers {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}

.flowers div {
  float: left;
  width: 90%;
  height: 68px;
  line-height: 68px;
  padding: 0 5%;
  background: #eee;
  margin: 0 0 1px;
  position: relative;
}
```

JS

```
  var $filterCheckboxes = $('input[type="checkbox"]');

  $filterCheckboxes.on('change', function() {

  var selectedFilters = {};

  $filterCheckboxes.filter(':checked').each(function() {

    if (!selectedFilters.hasOwnProperty(this.name)) {
      selectedFilters[this.name] = [];
    }

    selectedFilters[this.name].push(this.value);

  });

  // create a collection containing all of the filterable elements
  var $filteredResults = $('.flower');

  // loop over the selected filter name -> (array) values pairs
  $.each(selectedFilters, function(name, filterValues) {

    // filter each .flower element
    $filteredResults = $filteredResults.filter(function() {

        var matched = false,
        currentFilterValues = $(this).data('category').split(' ');

      // loop over each category value in the current .flower's data-category
      $.each(currentFilterValues, function(_, currentFilterValue) {

        // if the current category exists in the selected filters array
        // set matched to true, and stop looping. as we're ORing in each
        // set of filters, we only need to match once

        if ($.inArray(currentFilterValue, filterValues) != -1) {
          matched = true;
          return false;
        }
      });

      // if matched is true the current .flower element is returned
      return matched;

    });
  });

  $('.flower').hide().filter($filteredResults).show();

});
```

Comment: Which `div` are you planning to show/hide?

Comment: just check $filteredResults ==0 if yes then show whatever div you want to show

Comment: Sandeep Nayak,doesnt matter,for example a 100x100px red div

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check the length attribute of the results from the jQuery selector. Since the jQuery selector finds an array of elements, you can check the length attribute of the jQuery object.

```
if ($filteredResults.length == 0) {
    $("#divID").show();
} else {
    $("#divID").hide();
}
```